# How to set Django form initial value only one field?

Tags: django, django-forms

forms.py

```
class ExForm(forms.Form):
    a = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    b = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
    c = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['a'] = 'something value'
```

views.py

```
def view(request):
    form = ExForm(request.GET or None)
    return render(request, 'a.html', {'form': form})
```

I want to set an initial value to 'a' field only.
When I submit this form, b and c fields values not set in the form from request.GET.

It works.

```
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['a'] = 'something value'
        self.initial['b'] = request.b
        self.initial['c'] = request.c
```

I want to know how to set initial value only one field.
Do I set all field initial values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial) field's argument:

```
class ExForm(forms.Form):
    a = forms.CharField(max_length=100, initial='Some value')
    b = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
    c = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a **default** value to a particular FormField, you can specify it using `initial`:

```
class ExForm(forms.Form):
a = forms.CharField(max_length=100, initial="Any Value")
b = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
c = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
...
```

Or specifying a default value from choices, use `default='Some Value'`

```
SOME_CHOICES = [
         ('1','Value1')
         ('2','Value2')
]

    class ExForm(forms.Form):
a = forms.CharField(max_length=100, initial="Any Value")
b = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES, default='1')
c = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES, default='2')
...
```

Hope it clears your doubt.